# What is the MacOSX.sdk file? Where do I find it?

Tags: macos, xcode

I am trying to do a build of Cyanogenmod, that outputs the error:

```
Can not find SDK  at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

However, the `/Developer/SDKs` directory does not even exist. I know that most of the libraries have been moved to `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/`, but I don't know where to look. What is this **MacOSX.sdk** file? Where can I find it?

Also note that the wiki of Cyanogenmod says that I should Install the Mac OS X Developer Tools from my DVD, but I upgraded to Mavericks with the App Store. What do they mean by Developer Tools? I do have things like `make` and `gcc` (Command line tools in Xcode).

This is the wiki page I found the instruction to install dev tools from DVD:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Template:Build_on_Mac_OS_X#Install_Developer_Tools

Comment: The instructions are for an old OS (older than Snow Leopard) Developer tool;s are part of the Xcode install - now in App Store then as part of the OS release - I would get more up to date code

Comment: @Mark I am doing a CM build for kitkat, therefore it has to be code 2 generations older that the latest ones unfortunately. Aside that, how could I link the new SDK to the makefile? Or is building newer code the only solution?

Comment: kitkat is an Android OS name isn't it so why ask OS X questions?

Comment: @Mark Because the question is not asking about the actual Android build process or related, but rather about the OSX SDK. I should probably edit my comment to something like: Can I change the path from `/Developer/SDK` to `/Applications/Xcode.app/...`, or does the OSX SDK file no longer exist?

Comment: @klanomath Done. If you scroll to the top a bit, you will see how to build for mountain lion/mavericks. Can I still link some sort of `macosx.sdk` file from the XCode Contents?

Comment: @TheBro21 A virtual machine in VirtualBox/VMware Fusion/Parallels with Mountain Lion installed

Comment: @klanomath I can then either do a mountain lion VM, or I can also try new code instead. Please put the details about this macosx.sdk file, etc. in an answer.

Comment: @TheBro21 I'm just setting up a VM to check that

Comment: @klanomath You don't have to do that just for me. I will just simply use newer code to solve my problem.

Comment: This instruction solved it for me - https://trac.macports.org/wiki/SierraProblems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark in the comments the instructions are made for older versions of Xcode.

In my opinion you can simply link a MacOSX sdk to /Developer/SDKs:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Developer/SDKs
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

additionally you can add a link named MacOSX10.6.sdk

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

Another [tip](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78396) is to edit build/core/combo/mac_version.mk and changing:
mac_sdk_versions_supported := 10.6 10.7 10.8
to
mac_sdk_versions_supported := 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 10.10

---

I strongly recommend to use a virtual machine (Mountain Lion) and an older Xcode version (4.6.3). This version as well as all other versions are freely available with an Apple ID at [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Xcode used to install themselves and files into the /Developer folder.

This is no longer the case, so you would need to find / download the same version of Xcode that your package expects or update the package.

If you are a paid developer, you might be able to find that old package amongst the downloads and re-install it. Worst case, you could ask developer support for a download if you can't find it once you're logged in. This will likely be far easier than trying to change the code to work with the new Xcode setup/layout.